# Did the Trade Federation know Darth Sidious was Senator Palpatine? If so, why didn't they rat him out when they were apprehended by the Republic?

Tags: star-wars, sith, the-phantom-menace

One thing that's bothered me about Episode I is how Palpatine poorly disguises himself as Darth Sidious. He puts on a cloak, but part of his face is still visible! And this got me wondering; how did the Trade Federation never put two and two together and conclude on who he was? They had Senators who were **standing right near him** in the Senate chambers. So my question ultimately is: Did the Trade Federation really know who Palpatine was, and when he "betrayed" them in Episode I, why didn't they expose him and his plans? Or were they really that dumb not to figure that out?